# retrieve video fro pasteboard IOS

Tags: ios, swift, video, uipasteboard

I am copying video from `DocumentDirectory` to `Pasteboard` with this code .

```
let data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputurl))!
let pasteBoard: UIPasteboard = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pasteBoard.setData(data, forPasteboardType: String(kUTTypeVideo))
```

Now can anybody help me how to get this video and use in different place From pasteboard.

Answer (score 1):

See Objective-C code below, hope you can convert it to swift:

`APIs` for reading data from Pasteboard.

```
//returns data 
- (NSData *)dataForPasteboardType:(NSString *)pasteboardType;

//returns value
- (id)valueForPasteboardType:(NSString *)pasteboardType;
```

Example:

```
UIPasteboard * pasteboard=[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

NSData * data = [pasteboard dataForPasteboardType:(NSString*)kUTTypeVideo];
```

For more detail check article here:

http://hayageek.com/uipasteboard-example-read-write-share/

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of Ronak's answer

```
import MobileCoreServices
let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
let data = UIPasteboard.general.data(forPasteboardType: kUTTypeQuickTimeMovie as String)
```